# How could I have two names for the same atom in Prolog?

Tags: prolog

I want to have two names for the same atom in Prolog:

```
player(thomas).
player(william).
teamOfPlayer(thomas, redSocks).
teamOfPlayer(william, redSocks).
tom :- thomas.
will :- william.

teamOfPlayer(will, X).
```

I'd like to be able to refer to William using "william" atom and using "will" atom.

I know I could use a functor to define nicknames:

```
nick(tom, thomas).
nick(will, william).
```

and then,

```
nick(tom,X), teamOfPlayer(X, Y).
```

But I'd like to avoid all this verbosity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define whether something IS A something else

```
player(tom) :- !.
player(thomas) :- player(tom), !.
```

Now Prolog can see that if a player is named `thomas` or `tom`, the goal is met, so they are treated as the same person.

Your first solution is preferable though, as `nick(tom,X), teamOfPlayer(X, Y).` is much less specific and therefore much more extensible and easier to maintain as you're not changing existing code, you're just adding new facts to the knowledge base.

By defining both rules, you give Prolog two ways to answer for X.

```
%is X a member of team Y?
isPartOfTeam(X,Y) :- teamOfPlayer(X,Y).
isPartOfTeam(X,Y) :- nick(X, Z), teamOfPlayer(Z, Y).
```

By defining these general rules, X can be solved by either finding a team in the fact `teamOfPlayer(X,Y)` directly, or by trying *every single nickname you've defined for a specific instance of X*. That's where the power of Prolog comes in. You can have 10000 nicknames for 1 guy and Prolog will go through a process called backtracking to choicepoints to check them all through these two simple rules defined above.

Answer (score 5):

Implementation specific facilities are available for this purpose - and much more. Indeed, given that identity it's 'at heart' of logic, rewriting rules to fit different identification strategies is not an uncommon problem.

In SWI-Prolog, you can use the [expansion hooks](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=progtransform), more specifically [goal_expansion](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=goal_expansion/2)/2.

In your module, add near the end-of-file (just a convention, though)

```
:- multifile user:goal_expansion/2.
user:goal_expansion(will, william).
user:goal_expansion(tom, thomas).
```

*edit*

Sorry, I didn't debugged my suggestion, and it turns out to be incorrect.
A possible correction could be:

```erlang
alias(will,william).
alias(tom,thomas).

:- multifile user:goal_expansion/2.
user:goal_expansion(player(X), player(Y)) :-
    alias(X,Y).
user:goal_expansion(teamOfPlayer(X,T), teamOfPlayer(Y,T)) :-
    alias(X,Y).
```

We could make the overloading rules more generic, but the problem is deeply rooted in language core. Atoms carry the fundamental property (from the relational data model viewpoint) of **identity**, then we can 'overload' an atom only in **specific** contexts.

Comment: I am not able to run you solution: could you please suggest what I am doing wrong? Thanks
```
player(thomas).
player(william).
teamOfPlayer(thomas, redSocks).
teamOfPlayer(william, redSocks).

:- multifile user:goal_expansion/2.
user:goal_expansion(will, william).
user:goal_expansion(tom, thomas).

?- teamOfPlayer(will, X).
false.
```

Comment: mhmm ... there is still something that I do not understand. Now it is `True` that `will` and `tom` are players but when I query `teamOfPlayer(X, redSocks).` it only returns `will` and not `tom`
Thanks again for your answers, very much appreciated!